# Angular 6 - @input is not working

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components, angular-component-life-cycle

I have written a simple angular application to learn @input to communicate between components but the value is not being passed. I have also read some forums who have faced similar problems but none of the solutions prescribed are working for me. Please guide.

**app.componenent.html**

```
<app-task [prioirty]="'p1'"></app-task>
```

**task.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Task } from 'src/app/task/task';
import { TaskService } from 'src/app/task/services/task.service';
import {AppComponent} from 'src/app/app.component'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-task',
  templateUrl: './task.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./task.component.css'],
})
export class TaskComponent implements OnInit {     
  constructor(private taskService: TaskService) {        
  }      
  task: Task = new Task();
  @Input() priortiy: string; 
  ngOnInit() {
  }
  addTask(){
    alert(this.priortiy);
    this.taskService.addTask(this.task).subscribe((data : Task) => {}, error => console.error(error),() => console.log("Job Added successfully"));    
  }    
}
```

When I am trying to display the value of priority in an alert box, I get the value as undefined.

Let me know if anyone wants me to place the complete code.

Comment: i think it's typo problem : prioirty vs priortiy

Comment: My bad @Sajeetharan, the timing of the answer was closed hence the mistake

Comment: LOL even the answers have the wrong spelling. Perhaps this might be useful [Code Spell Checker](https://github.com/Jason-Rev/vscode-spell-checker)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo,

Change from

```
 @Input() priortiy: string;
```

To

```
 @Input() prioirty: string;
```

and alert too,

```
alert(this.prioirty);
```